# How do I limit the iterations in a while loop?

Tags: infinite-loop

Is there a way to limit the number of iterations in a while loop? Right now I am cleaning up the code, and for now if I make a mistake, the loop keeps going forever.  I'd like to be able to limit the number of times it will run through while I am working on it.  Is that possible?

Comment: start with `i=0`, use `i++` in each iteration and add a condtion e.g.`And[test, i < 100]`?

Comment: The way I'd do it is to initialize `i` with the number of iterations you want to define as your maximum, and have it count down: `And[test, i-- == 0]`. Then if you want to have infinite iterations later, initialize `i` with a negative number. But this is really a matter of taste; counting down traditionally was done because of the `JCXZ` x86 instruction. It's obviously not really relevant to *Mathematica*, being an interpreted language.

Comment: Does the body of your loop run at least once? You could use Do[] instead of While[].

Answer (score 8):

As an alternative to a manual check of the iterator, as proposed by Kuba, you could refactor to use [`NestWhile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NestWhile.html) by converting your body and test to functions without parameters:

```
n = 1; NestWhile[(Print[n]; n++) &, , (n > 0) &, 1, 7];
```

The test `n > 0` would normally result in an infinite loop, but here it is limited to `7`.